# use enum type to manage storage order

Tags: c++, enums

I'm trying to use enum types to indexig some array but I want to allow different ordering of the vector depending on some option. In the class I also want functions that take the enum variable as input and use it as it should.

The solution I found is the following

```
#include<iostream>
#include<array>
#include<vector>

struct A{
  struct XYZ{
    enum coord{X=0,Y,Z};
  };
  struct YZX{
    enum coord{Y=0,Z,X};
  };
  struct ZXY{
    enum coord{Z=0,X,Y};
  };
  std::array<std::vector<float>,3> val;
  void resize(int opt, size_t dim){
    val[opt].resize(dim);
    return;
  }
  void printsize(){
    for(auto & i : val){
      std::cout << i.size() << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return;
  }
};

int main(){
  A foo1;
  A foo2;
  A foo3;
  foo1.resize(XYZ::X,10);
  foo2.resize(YZX::X,10);
  foo3.resize(ZXY::X,10);
  std::cout << "Size foo1\n";
  foo1.printsize();
  std::cout << "Size foo2\n";
  foo2.printsize();
  std::cout << "Size foo3\n";
  foo3.printsize();
  return 0;
}
```

What I don't like in this solution is that my function resize takes an integer type as input and there's no type control of the enum.

Is there any other smarter solution? Am I doing something considered as anti-pattern?

Thank you

Comment: actually since C++11, you can use "enum class" that are strongly typed enums

Comment: @eddie: I know the possibility of using "enum class" but, since I can't inherit an enum (say XYZ) from a "BaseEnum", I can't write one general "resize" method and I would need three separate methods with a copy-paste of the content and three different signatures, which it seems to me aginst the OOP principles.

Comment: I have posted a new solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to modify the member function `resize` (three parameters instead of two) and exploit the type safety of the `enum class`es:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include<iostream>
    #include<array>
    #include<vector>

    struct A{

        enum class Coordinate
        {
            X = 0,
            Y = 1,
            Z = 2
        };

        enum class Permutation
        {
            XYZ = 0,
            ZXY = 1,
            YZX = 2
        };

        std::array<std::vector<float>,3> val;


        /* resize takes three parameters now */
        void resize(Permutation p, Coordinate c, size_t dim)
        {

            int  index = ( static_cast<int>(p) + static_cast<int>(c) ) % 3 ;

            val[index].resize(dim);
            return;
        }

        void printsize(){
            for(auto & i : val){
                std::cout << i.size() << " ";
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
            return;
        }
    };



int main()
{

    A foo1;
    A foo2;
    A foo3;
    foo1.resize(A::Permutation::XYZ, A::Coordinate::X,10); 
    foo2.resize(A::Permutation::YZX, A::Coordinate::X,10); 
    foo3.resize(A::Permutation::ZXY, A::Coordinate::X,10); 
    std::cout << "Size foo1\n";
    foo1.printsize();
    std::cout << "Size foo2\n";
    foo2.printsize();
    std::cout << "Size foo3\n";
    foo3.printsize();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about an `Index` class, constructible from several `enum class`es?

```
struct A
{
    enum class XYZ {X,Y,Z};
    enum class YZX {Y,Z,X};
    enum class ZXY {Z,X,Y};

    struct Index
    {
        int value;
        operator int() const {return value;}
        Index(XYZ value) : value(int(value)) {}
        Index(YZX value) : value(int(value)) {}
        Index(ZXY value) : value(int(value)) {}
    };

    std::array<std::vector<float>, 3> val;

    void resize(Index opt, size_t dim)
    {
        val[opt].resize(dim);
    }

    void printsize() const
    {
        for (const auto &i : val)
             std::cout << i.size() << ' ';
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
};
```

Comment: that's a good workaround but I thought that such simple problem would have a simpler solution than rely on an additional class.

Comment: @user8066678 You could overload `resize()` for each enum, but that's somewhat ugly if you ask me.

Comment: I totally agree with the uglyness of the overloading